# Pokemon java program, making a team? Array maybe?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and am making a pokemon game, I've run into a  problem, i'm not quite sure how to make a "team"; i have created a class for the pokemon, and opponents

```
class pokemon {
   String name; 
   String type; 
   String hp;
   String attack;
}
class opponent {
   String name;
   String poke1;
   String poke2;
   String poke3;
}




    public static void main(String []args) {
       Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
       //trainers pokemon 
       pokemon a = new pokemon();
       a.name    ="pika"; 
       a.type    ="elec"; 
       a.hp      ="100";
       a.attack  = "50";
       pokemon b = new pokemon();
       b.name    ="tor"; 
       b.type    ="fire"; 
       b.hp      ="99";
       b.attack  = "99";
       pokemon c = new pokemon();
       c.name    ="squirt"; 
       c.type    ="water"; 
       c.hp      ="50";
       c.attack  = "80";
       pokemon d = new pokemon();
       d.name    ="char"; 
       d.type    ="fire"; 
       d.hp      ="180";
       d.attack  = "80";
       pokemon e = new pokemon();
       e.name    ="cynda"; 
       e.type    ="fire"; 
       e.hp      ="70";
       e.attack  = "50";
       pokemon f = new pokemon();
       f.name    ="no"; 
       f.type    ="no"; 
       f.hp      ="50";
       f.attack  ="50";
       // going to have user choose who he wants      
       //opponents pokemon
       pokemon g = new pokemon();
       g.name    ="pika"; 
       g.type    ="elec"; 
       g.hp      ="100";
       g.attack  = "50";
       pokemon h = new pokemon();
       h.name    ="tor"; 
       h.type    ="fire"; 
       h.hp      ="99";
       h.attack  = "99";
       pokemon i = new pokemon();
       i.name    ="squirt"; 
       i.type    ="water"; 
       i.hp      ="50";
       i.attack  = "80";
       pokemon j = new pokemon();
       j.name    ="char"; 
       j.type    ="fire"; 
       j.hp      ="180";
       j.attack  = "80";
       pokemon k = new pokemon();
       k.name    ="cynda"; 
       k.type    ="fire"; 
       k.hp      ="70";
       k.attack  = "50";
       pokemon l = new pokemon();
       l.name    ="no"; 
       l.type    ="no"; 
       l.hp      ="50";
       l.attack  = "50";
       //opponents   
       opponent aa = new opponent();
       aa.name = "red";
       aa.poke1=k.name ;
       aa.poke2=i.name;
       aa.poke3=j.name;

       opponent ab = new opponent();
       ab.name = "blue";
       ab.poke1=k.name ;
       ab.poke2=l.name;
       ab.poke3=j.name;
     }    
}
```

All i have done so far is just set the names equal to the poke1,poke2,poke3 but i have no idea how to put the whole pokemon in the opponent's team.

Comment: Instead of having `String` to represent the pokemon each `opponent` has, instead make them of type `pokemon`.

Comment: Where is your Tester class?

Comment: @Obicere so `String` Should just be replaced with `pokemon`?

Comment: @prudhvi Uhh tester class? I'm pretty new to java not sure what that is, I'll look it up though

Comment: @jesusizquierdo to do what you wanted, yes. But I'd suggest reading through some more OOP tutorials and build a better structure for this.

Comment: Arraylist<pokemon> team = new ArrayList<>(); array list is easy to work with.

Comment: `p` and `n` should be small @jesson

Comment: Why not scroll down and check my answer ?

Comment: @DarshanJain Sorry i wanted to thank these guys for their input, I did see your answer and thought it was great! Really useful thanks!

Comment: If you understood my answer , are able to workout with it then accept my answer .

Comment: @DarshanJain Will do and thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array of `pokemon`

In `main()`

```
pokemon[]  trainer = new pokemon[6];
trainer[0] = new pokemon();
trainer[0].name = "pikachu";
//...
//trainer[1] .. Till 5
```

And `opponent` could be

```
class opponent{ 
String name;
pokemon[] pokes; }
```

You can set them similarily as `trainer`

Edit: As I have my own pokemon game, just wanted to clear you concept a bit more.
Create a class `pokemons` which contain name , hp , etc of all pokemons. Change the `pokemon` class to rather take only one object of `pokemons` i.e.,

```
class pokemon{
pokemons info ; }
```

In the `pokemon` class you can add other things like nick name, current power ,exp

Comment: Did you really understood ?

Comment: I am not gonna eat you so if you have any doubts tell. http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/array-of-objects. @jesus